# Image width 100% on Mobile Devices in Newspaper Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, wordpress, css, width

I have problems with css image width styling in my wordpress theme. The Image width is set to 100% however the image appears in it's original size. and overflow is somehow hidden. However I couldn't figure out which element is causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

http://www.dailycat.de/19-gruende-warum-man-katzen-lieben-muss-758/

Thx, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: check your media queries... It does not resize image when screen is smaller than 750px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your .row-fluid has `display:table;` browsers render it as a table, so when you set `table-layout:fixed;` browsers set the width of the table to 100%, ignoring the width of it's cells. Your images have bigger width than the browsers canvas on mobile and when you have `table-layout:auto;` (default value), the width of the container becomes the width of the cell (in your case - the width of the image)

More information about `table-layout` on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

This code should fix your problem

```
.row-fluid {table-layout:fixed;}
```

Comment: did fix the problem on chrome on desktop however not working on iphone

Comment: it's pretty weird. In safari works resizing after resizing browser image?

Comment: Add `.row-fluid {display:block;}`, set this inside some media query for mobile device width. For some reason mobile safari doesn't respect `table-layout:fixed;` maybe something overwrites this

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript on your wordpress theme which overide your css. When you inspect your image there is `width` and `height` attribut generated it also affect the containers and wrapper. You have to find where in your theme to disable this behavior (clean)